# Folder access rights and permission

Tags: file-permissions, access-rights

How do I setup a folder permission to allow user to move files from a subfolder to another subfolder but not allowing deletion and renaming the files?

I have this new Excel VBA program that will create a PDF report (final report) to the folder and at the same time automatically move CSV files (raw data) to another subfolder. I already set user's permission with only 'Write' option but I am getting error during PDF creation process. I am very certain that this error caused by access rights and permission to folder as the users are not given 'Modify' access.

I am fully aware that if 'Modify' access given to the users, they can modify the data of the report and also deleting them. But due to compliance issue, I need to prevent users from renaming and deleting the content of the folder and at the same time able to create PDF file and move those CSV file. Is it achievable?

I have tried changing destination of PDF report to be created to another folder with 'Modify' access. However, users still able to delete and rename the files created. I need to prevent that from happening due to compliance issue.